# map in Option cannot be applied to <method reference>

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

i have the following code in intellij 12.1.6

```
final Optional<Obj> optObj = Optional.ofNullable(objParam);
final Optional<ype> Type =  optObj.map(optObj::getMessage).map(Message::getType);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but I get the following error:

```
 map Function<? Obj, ?> in Option cannot be applied to <method reference>
```

is this an intellij thing or an issue with a class (Obj) from another group at work that just doesn't support java 8 maps for null pointer checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optObj` refers to your `Optional` instance. [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) does not contain a `getMessage` method. You probably meant to do `Obj::getMessage`.